# Object #<s> has no method 'apply' Angular Reload

Tags: javascript, angularjs

My issue is that I want to be able call my `reloadPage()` inside my `ng-change=saveCurrentTemplate` but this seems to not work:

```
 $scope.reloadPage = () ->
    getControllerScope "Ctrl", (scope) ->
      $scope.bb_main = ""
      $scope.apply()
      $scope.show_page 

  $scope.saveCurrentTemplate = () ->
    $templateCache.put($scope.currentCache, $scope.templateContents)
    $scope.reloadPage()
```

What I am trying to achieve is that as you make changes to the textarea the content also updates. However I am getting the following: `Object #<s> has no method 'apply'`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use `$scope.$apply` instead of `$scope.apply`

[Docs reference](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24rootScope.Scope#methods_%24apply)

Comment: Here's a link to the docs: http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.$rootScope.Scope#methods_$apply

Comment: This is what I was after >_<